# Electron: .setAttribute not working (different)

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am trying to use .setAttribute on the following:

```
   <div class="media-body">
                <small>Total MA'ers found</small>
                <h2 id="totalma" class="media-heading animate-number" data-value="29" data-animation-duration="1500">0</h2>
              </div>
```

With:

```
document.getElementById('totalma').setAttribute("data-value", 90);
```

When I try this in my browser on the .htm file, it works fine. However, with Electron, it does not. The value does not change to 90. What could the issue be?

Both codes are stored in home.htm

Comment: How do you check your attribute's updated value?

Comment: it is working. I checked from developers tool

Comment: In browser it does work, but with Electron it does not for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

> The name of a custom data attribute in Javascript is the name of the same HTML attribute but in camelCase and with no dashes, dots, etc.

So here in your case this will work

```
document.getElementById('totalma').setAttribute("dataValue", 90);
```

You can find more information on custom data-* attribute here:-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset